# Problema tarea Cron 1and1

Tags: hosting, cron, crontab

tengo un problema al realizar las copias de seguridad de mi base de datos que tengo alojadas en el

> Servidor 1and1

, el caso es que tienen una herramienta para realizar las tareas `Cron` pero es una basura, y directamente ellos me han dicho que pase de ella y que la realice con `crontab`, el caso es que si ejecuto este comando desde `ssh` :

```
mysqldump -hhost.db.1and1.com -uusuariobasedatos -pcontraseña basededatos> Urbanos/GestionPersonal/cron/copia_seguridad$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql
```

Me crea la copia de seguridad sin problema, pero desde `crontab` tengo definida esta línea:

```
*/15 * * * * mysqldump -hhost.db.1and1.com -uusuariobasedatos -pclave basededatos> Urbanos/GestionPersonal/cron/copia_seguridad$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql
```

y me llega la confirmación de que la tarea `cron` se ha ejecutado, esta bien definida? si no es así como lo podría hacer? ya que en `1and1` se niegan a ayudarme

Comment: Revisa en la ubicación `Urbanos/GestionPersonal/cron/` si las copias se están creando.

Comment: @A.Cedano Buenas, en primer lugar muchas gracias por contestar, si uso el comando por ssh directamente me crea perfectamente la copia de seguridad en esa ubicacion, el problema es que la tarea cron no lo ejecuta

Comment: Para un hosting como 1AND1 programar un cron debería ser algo simple, no creo que sean tan mediocres hasta ese nivel. En tu pregunta das muy pocos detalles para poder ayudarte. ¿Dónde y cómo programaste el Cron? ¿Usaste CPanel por ejemplo para ello? ¿Te aparece que el Cron de programó correctamente? Se necesita ese tipo de detalles para saber cuál es la situación.

Comment: Tengo creado dentro de la carpeta cron un archivo cron.sh con ese comando en el interior y con el cpanel configuro que se ejecute, pero no se ejecuta. Y luego ademas me conecto a 1and1 por ssh y utilizando el comando crontab - e defino el segundo comando que muestro con los **** que es la tarea cron y tampoco se ejecuta, y se supone que esa tarea cron esta programada para ejecutarse cada 15 minutos

Comment: @A.Cedano y si son así de cutres o mas, en 000webhost, osease el hostinger gratuito es mucho mas simple definir las tareas cronç

Comment: No creo que sean tan cutres. Es muy probable que estés escribiendo mal el comando o algo así. Una cosa que puedes hacer es guardar el comando en un archivo y mandar a ejecutar ese archivo desde el cron (usando cPanel), nada más, no te líes con tantas vueltas. Yo uso Bluehost y es así como ejecuto los backups de la base de datos y todo marcha a la perfección.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98585/discussion-between-ketemeto-and-a-cedano).